# gdal_translate grib2 to xyz producing unexpected lat/lon centroid

Tags: gdal, gdal-translate

I am finding unexpected lat/lon values in an output CSV file after converting grib2 to XYZ in gdal_translate. The grib2 file can be [found here on Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jMkVtloUa-NP-Z11aFrEoHGu5Ai0NTwl/view?usp=sharing) in case anyone wants to look at the data.

I am using gdal_translate to output a CSV file using that data. (My command also filters the results by removing nodata values.) Here is my command in full, exactly as I am using it with the file above :

```
gdal_translate -q -of xyz -co ADD_HEADER_LINE=NO -co COLUMN_SEPARATOR="," -co DECIMAL_PRECISION=4 MRMS_MergedReflectivityAtLowestAltitude_00.50_20210717-203243.grib2 /vsistdout | findstr /V /C:"-999" /C:"-99"  > output.csv
```

I am a beginner/intermediate user with gdal_translate, so I may be missing something obvious with this. Using an external viewer on known correct data, I compared my output lat/lon to it. The lat/lon point in my data currently sits to the top/left of the cell, but neither in the exact corner or as a centroid. It seems to move from file to file, but it's always within the correct cell. The green box in the image below is the cell using my example data, and the X is where my lat/lon coords are taking me.

What are the latitude and longitude values supposed to be - a centroid or the top left corner? Why does it not align with either one? Ideally, I would like gdal_translate to give me the centroid. Is there a way to do this?

*Note/Edit : I thought the -co DECIMAL_PRECISION=4 might have been the problem, but after increasing the precision I realized it is not the problem.*

[image]

Comment: Can't replicate (not using Windows so can't test your exact command). I get expected [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAmGs.png) with `gdal_translate -q -of XYZ -co ADD_HEADER_LINE=YES input.grib2 /vsistdout/ | ogr2ogr -f CSV -sql "SELECT X,Y,Z FROM layer WHERE Z not in ('-999', '-99')" output.csv CSV:/vsistdin/ -lco SEPARATOR=SPACE`